# ABS Fixed but traction light still on

Tags: honda, abs

I've gone through the mill a bit lately getting my ABS sensor (Driver Front) sorted.  I've replaced the sensor, and had the wheel bearing (and so, also sensor ring) changed, and after a reset from the SnapOn, the ABS light is out, which was my main aim.

However, the VSA lights remain on.  Initially the VSA Active light is on, and the VSA Warning lamp comes on after a half mile.

I'm guessing this is related, and also that it's not necessarily a problem, but thought you guys might know better.  My guesses:

- Nothing wrong, but needs a reset that only the Honda OBD machine would manage.
- Sensor is returning translatable data, but the ECU doesn't like that it's a pattern part, not a manufacturer original.
- VSA needs resetting with better OBD/Dealer's OBD.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you drove a bit? Sometimes ABS is checked after a few minutes of driving.

Comment: is the check engine light on? a snapon scanner will reset the vsa light what software version are you running?

Comment: @com2ghz About 100 miles, yeah, in roughly 3 trips.

Comment: @Ben No, it's not.  Dunno about the version, it's the garages, not mine.  Mine is 2014.

Answer (score 1):

I don't personally know Hondas well at all but my money is on that the steering angle sensor needs to be re-calibrated as this is the other major system involved in traction control once you've taken wheel speed sensors out of the equation.